# How to output bash to text file in real time correctly?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I want to do this and save this to a text file say abc.txt.

```
top | grep "Cpu(s)"
```

I usderstand I can do this in bash

```
top | stdbuf -o0 grep "Cpu(s)" > abc.txt
```

I get my output correctly but when I open the txt file in gedit, it looks like this:

​​

```
Cpu(s): (B [m [39;49m (B [m  1.0% (B [m [39;49mus, (B [m [39;49m (B [m  0.3% (B [m [39;49msy, (B [m [39;49m (B [m  0.6% (B [m [39;49mni, (B [m [39;49m (B [m 97.9% (B [m [39;49mid, (B [m [39;49m (B [m  0.1% (B [m [39;49mwa, (B [m [39;49m (B [m  0.0% (B [m [39;49mhi, (B [m [39;49m (B [m  0.0% (B [m [39;49msi, (B [m [39;49m (B [m  0.0% (B [m [39;49mst (B [m [39;49m [K
Cpu(s): (B [m [39;49m (B [m  0.7% (B [m [39;49mus, (B [m [39;49m (B [m  1.0% (B [m [39;49msy, (B [m [39;49m (B [m  0.0% (B [m [39;49mni, (B [m [39;49m (B [m 98.3% (B [m [39;49mid, (B [m [39;49m (B [m  0.0% (B [m [39;49mwa, (B [m [39;49m (B [m  0.0% (B [m [39;49mhi, (B [m [39;49m (B [m  0.0% (B [m [39;49msi, (B [m [39;49m (B [m  0.0% (B [m [39;49mst (B [m [39;49m [K`

Instead of this:

    ​Cpu(s):  1.0%us,  0.3%sy,  0.6%ni, 97.9%id,  0.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
    Cpu(s):  0.7%us,  1.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 98.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `top -b` to remove all special display characters:

```
top -b | grep "Cpu(s)" > abc.txt
```